# Enable mongodb auth, website not loading

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

Right now I have a website hosted and I am using mongodb. I can connect to the database using my credentials, example:

```
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://myUserAdmin:abc123@localhost:27017/admin");
```

When I turn on authentication in my mongodb.conf folder, my website refuses to load and says it cannot connect. However, the mongoclient details are definitely correct. It lets me add and retrieve from the database using the code above, but as soon as I enable auth, it fails for some reason. Anyone have any insight?

Thank you if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Which database did you create user `myUserAdmin` in ?

Comment: In admin database. Used  role: "userAdminAnyDatabase". The database I am accessing is different though

Comment: I also cannot connect when I change localhost to my public ip address. So maybe the problem lies somewhere there? I can't figure it out

Comment: In the mongod.conf file you need to bind the address like this bind_ip = 127.0.0.1. In alternative, you can bind it to all with 0.0.0.0 (not recommended if you don't have a firewall)

Comment: You have the `myUserAdmin` as admin user with `userAdminAnyDatabase`. You'll use `myUserAdmin` to create user for your database. `Use <replacewithyourdatabase>` followed by 
`db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myTester",
    pwd: "xyz123",
    roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: <replacewithyourdatabase> }]
  }
)` and update your `$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://myUserAdmin:abc123@localhost:27017/<replacewithyourdatabase>");` and try

Comment: Thank you both. It works now!!